# Render date on datatables

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datatables

When i try to display the date on datatables by ajax.

The date value become   /Date(1665507600000)/ and then I try to render it with

```
render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ", "DD/MM/YYYY")
```

the value of the date become "Invalid date".

The date value in SQL is "2022-10-12 00:00:00.000"

It was display fine when I use HTML Action.

I appreciate every help.

Comment: have you tried this `render: DataTable.render.datetime('DD/MM/YYYY')` ? or if possible can you add minimal example ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this render instead

```
render: DataTable.render.datetime('DD/MM/YYYY')
```